# Grep between 1st occurence to 1st other occurence

Tags: text-processing, grep

It's my first question here ! I've tried many grep, still not found what I wanted ...

So, here we are.

I have many many files on my Ubuntu machine that contain things like this :

```
{"group":{"name":"Subdivision01","id":"94827-20934-23085"}*manytext*
{"group":{"name":"Department28","id":"11672-23517-87241"}*manytext*
{"group":{"name":"Division07","id":"86267-91634-22516"}*manytext*
```

I want to only take **`Subdivision01`** and **`Division05`** and **`Departement14`** (which have different length)

So it means **between** the **1st** occurence of `":"` and the **1st** occurence of `","`
==> I don't know how to do this ...

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Use `awk` instead of `grep`

Comment: Hey, if you read well you can see that the first is : ```":{"``` but not ```":"```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, which support [lookarounds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<="name":").+?(?=",)' file
Subdivision01
Department28
Division07
```

The `-P` enables PCRE support and the `-o` tells `grep` to only print the matching portion of a line.

The `(?<=foo)bar` is a *positive lookbehind*: it will match `bar` only if it is immediately preceded by `foo`. Then, `bar(?=foo)` is a positive *lookahead*, it will match `bar` only if it is immediately followed by `foo`. So, the regex we use is looking for the shortest string (`.+?`) that is between a `"name":"` and a `",`.